# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactCurrentOwner')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-dom, react-test-renderer

I have an npm monorepo which contains web apps (React 18), mobile apps (React-Native 0.71/React 18) and shared libraries. I am also using npm overrides to fix React versions, this has not changed. After some updates, when I run Jest tests I get the following error in **just one** of my projects:

```
 FAIL  hooks/useFoo.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReactCurrentOwner')

    > 1 | import { create, snapshotOf } from "jest-snapshot-propifier";
        | ^
      2 | import { useCallback as useCallbackLib } from "react";
      3 | import {
      4 |     useDispatch as useDispatchLib,

      at ReactCurrentOwner (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:496:46)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:18643:4)
      at Object.require (../../node_modules/react-test-renderer/index.js:6:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (hooks/useFoo.test.tsx:1:1)
```

All the detailed answers I can find are 5 years old and talk of version mismatches between `React`, `React-Dom` and `React-Test-Renderer`. But I don't think this is the case for me, or at least I don't think it is:

```
$ npm ls react-test-renderer react react-dom

├─┬ @common/lib@1.0.0 -> ./common/lib
│ ├─┬ @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.1
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ next-redux-wrapper@8.1.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
│ ├── react-test-renderer@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0
...
├─┬ jest-snapshot-propifier@1.5.4
│ ├── react-test-renderer@18.2.0 deduped
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└─┬ react-test-renderer@18.2.0
  ├─┬ react-shallow-renderer@16.15.0
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped invalid: "17.0.2" from node_modules/bar //this is from the overrides in my root p.j
  └── react@18.2.0 deduped
```

Is this the same issue as the 5yr old ones, and if so how/why?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem via poking around in the `node_modules`

```
node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js


21| var ReactSharedInternals = React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED;
22| console.log("", React)
```

Printed

```
     {
      useCallback: [Function: mockConstructor] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
        getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
      }
    }
```

And there was the problem (although I don't know why it had changed)

Back in the test file:

```
jest.mock("react", () => ({
    useCallback: jest.fn()
}));
```

just needed to updating to

```
jest.mock("react", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("react"),
    useCallback: jest.fn(),
}));
```